# Creating Multiple Instances of a class and distinguishing between them

Tags: c#

I'm working on a project that creates a class with a few pieces of information. For example

```
public Player(string Playername, int PlayerRating)
        {
            name = Playername;
            rating = PlayerRating;
        }
```

My question is how can I create a way to distinguish between multiple Instances  of the Player class to updating Rating. I tried some kind of ID number to select the correct class. I thought maybe I could make an array of ID pointers and have each point to a different player.

edit: changed from Copies to Instances. 
edit:  For clarification on what the programs function is. The idea is to have a large group a "Players" and have them play a matches outside of this project. Then after the match is over I come back to this and update the ratings of the players.

Comment: It is not really clear what you are asking.  Why don't you just put the instances into an array or list or dictionary?

Comment: Im sorry, the best way I can describe it is if I make a Player (Bob, 1000) play a chess match vs Player (Joe,1200). i have two copies of the Player class and after the match i would want to change the values of the players rating. My problem is I'm not sure how I can Select Bobs Player Class and set his rating to a new value and then do the same for Joe. 

I hope this explains more

Comment: @jarrhead13 language is important here. You are looking to differentiate instances of a class, not the classes themselves. A "copy of a class" would be interpreted by most programmers as creating a copy of the type. This summary may help you reword the question to make it clear what you are asking:  https://alfredjava.wordpress.com/2008/07/08/class-vs-object-vs-instance/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are probably looking for is a [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx). A dictionary can have a key and a value. No two keys can be the same. The key and value can be an integer, string, or any object (class) you want. Is your PlayerName unique? If so, you can use the PlayerName as the key when adding to the dictionary.  Otherwise, you can generate a Guid and use that.  Something like this:

```
// Keep a dictionary of all players
Dictionary<string, Player> PlayerDict = new Dictionary<string, Player>();

public void addNewPlayer(string newPlayerName)
{
    // create new player with rating of 0
    Player newPlayer = new Player(newPlayerName, 0);
    // check if the player already exists in dictionary
    if (!PlayerDict.ContainsKey(newPlayer.name))
    {
        // player doesn't exist / add player
        PlayerDict.Add(newPlayer.name, newPlayer);
    }
}

public void changePlayerRating(String name, int newRating)
{
    // check if player exists in dictionary
    if (PlayerDict.ContainsKey(name))
    {
        // player exists - change player rating
        PlayerDict[name].rating = newRating;
    }
    else
    {
        // player doesnt exist - add the player
        addNewPlayer(name);
    }
}

public class Player
{
    public string name { get; }
    public int rating { get; set; }

    public Player(string Playername, int PlayerRating)
    {
        name = Playername;
        rating = PlayerRating;
    }
}
```

Then you can just do this:

```
addNewPlayer("John");
changePlayerRating("John", 1000);
```

Or increment the rating like this:

```
PlayerDict["John"].rating += 10
```

Comment: You should not use public fields. Use properties instead.

Comment: @svick This is an example, not a discussion about best practices. In an effort to keep the example very simple I used public fields, and there is nothing wrong with it depending on your use cases and design. So I don't appreciate the down vote.  I have edited it, and added getter and setter even though it didn't matter in this discussion.

Comment: @DonaldSander - I agree with svick. You should use good practices when answering questions here. This is a learning site and where possible we should show good programming practice.

Comment: @DonaldSander this is the best answer. Thank you. 1 question i have. In the ChangePlayerRating function  

`PlayerDict[p.name].rating = newRating;`


is p.name supposed to be Player.name ?

Comment: Also, in `ChangePlayerRating`, when an existing player is not found, it creates a new one, but never sets the rating on it. Should be an easy fix.

Comment: Sorry @jarrhead13 it is supposed to just be `name`. I had made a lot of last minute changes and forgot to change that. Also was in a hurry. I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Based on discussion in comments you probably want something more like this than my other answer. `LoadPlayersFromDisk` and `SavePlayersToDisk` would have to be added on your own.  Showing you how to do that here is really beyond the scope of this question.  Feel free to create a new question (after doing some research) about it though, once you get to that point.

This doesn't cover how to handle what happens when you use the name of a `Player` that isn't in the `Dictionary`, or how to add new `Players` either, but it should give you a good start. Donald Sander's answer shows some good ways to handle both those situations.

Player.cs:

```
public class Player
{
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public int Rank{get;set;
}
```

Main.cs:

```
var players = new Dictionary<string, Player>();

LoadPlayersFromDisk();

var winnerName = Console.ReadLine("Enter the name of the winner:");
var winner = players[winnerName];
winner.Rank++;
Console.WriteLine($"{winner.Name}'s rank has increased to {winner.Rank}")

SavePlayersToDisk();
```

Comment: You should consider the answer given by @DonaldSander also. His is much more through than this mine.

Answer (score 0):

> the best way I can describe it is if I make a Player (Bob, 1000) play a chess match vs Player (Joe,1200). i have two copies of the Player class and after the match i would want to change the values of the players rating. My problem is I'm not sure how I can Select Bobs Player Class and set his rating to a new value and then do the same for Joe.

I'm not sure I understand the question correctly, but since each player is in a separate variable, you should be able to just update the rating using those variables.

In code, it could look something like:

```
class Player
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public int Rating { get; set; }

    public Player(string name, int rating)
    {
        Name = name;
        Rating = rating;
    }
}

static class Game
{
    static void Play(Player player1, Player player2)
    {
        // code to play the game here, also sets player1NewRating and player2NewRating

        player1.Rating = player1NewRating;
        player2.Rating = player2NewRating;
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        var bob = new Player("Bob", 1000);
        var joe = new Player("Joe", 1200);

        Play(bob, joe);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `Player` class *already* has a way to distinguish between players, namely, the `Name` property. There are many ways you could do this, but here is just one example.

If you have a `List<Player>` called `Players`, you can find the `Player` names "John" like this:

```
var player = Players.Where(p => p.Name == "John").First();
```

After that line, `player` will contain the first `Player` instance with the `Name` of "John".

Another options is to use a `Dictionary<string, Player>`, which would work like `var player = Players["John"]`.

Both of these methods rely on `Name` being unique, no 2 players could have the same name.

---

After thinking on your question more, you might just be confused about how to track the players within a single game.  This is usually covered pretty early in computer classes, so forgive me if you already know this.

This is the concept of "references".  We deal with 3 things in the area as programmers, variables, instances, and references. `var player` defines a variable. `new Player()` creates a new *instance* of `Player`, and return a *reference* to it.  You can place that reference in to a variable by combining those 2 statements with `var player = new Player()`. The `player` *variable* now holds a *reference* to an *instance* of `Player`.

If we were talking about houses, the `class` would be the blueprint.  Only one of them would ever exist at a time, and it defines how to build a house.  An `instance` is what is created whenever someone uses the blueprint to build a house.  You could have 10 separate houses, all built from the same blueprint. Each of these houses would be distinct houses, but have the exact same physical features.

In a game, you could have multiple players, they could be stored in a `List<Player>`, and your game could keep a `currentPlayer` variable around that contains an `int` with the index of who's turn it is.

As a quick example, this is an easy game loop (without the actual logic for a turn).  Most likely you would also want to persist the `Player` instances to something more permanent, like a database.  The same basic loop could be used for any number of players, and it will move through each one, turn by turn.

```
bool gameOver = false;
var players = new List<Player>();
players.Add(new Player("John"));
players.Add(new Player("Bob"));
int currentPlayerIndex = 0;
Player winner = null;

while(!gameOver)
{
    var currentPlayer = players[currentPlayerIndex];

    //Do a player's turn here, "currentPlayer" will be whoever's turn it is.
    //set won to true if the current player won the game.

    if(won)
    {
       currentPlayer.Rating++;
       gameOver = true;
    }

    currentPlayerIndex++;
    if(currentPlayerIndex >= players.Count)
    {
        currentPlayerIndex = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a really a lot of help. The idea is to have a large group a "Players" and have them play a match outside of this project. then after the match is over I come back to this and update the ratings of the players. I have never used a dictionary but will give it a try. the way you explained it as long as the names are all different I should be able to access the rating data in their respective "profile". to clairify if i have the dictionary setup i would use

var player = Players.Where(p => p.Name == "John").First();

to access the individual players?

Comment: Ahh, I see.  You aren't actually writing the *game* here, you are just writing the software to track player rankings outside the game.  That is a pretty important distinction.  You should probably consider adding that to your question so that you get better answers.

Comment: Yes, that is basically correct, though you mixed up the concept of `List` and `Dictionary`. The `Dictionary` would be accessed like `players["John"]`, not `players.Where(p=>p=="John")`, that's for `List`. The `Dictionary` acts like a database of players, though it would reset its self every time the program was started.  Eventually you probably want to look at saving that contents of that dictionary to a file at the end of every game, and then loading it at the start.

Comment: Based on what you've said. I'll add another answer addressing this.

Comment: exactly what i was thinking with saving to a file! thank you, you've been a great huge help.